# Power BI Embedded - Dynamic Binding

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I would like to design the dashboards & reports and embed them in my web application.

Users will just be using our web application.

I want to create the dashboards/reports once for all our users to use.

Then I require the dashboards/reports to have dynamic binding to connect to different datasets/databases based on the user's login.

I.e. when users log in as Company A they will only see “ Company A” data presented on the dashboard.

When users log in to “ Company B” they will only see “Company B” data presented on the same dashboard.

However, the most important thing is to be able to change the connection/data at run time dynamically through the web application code.

Is it possible to achieve and how can I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic binding is not a solution in your case. You should use [Row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls) for that.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks for your reply and suggestion.